# How to enable a button when all the fields of form get field?

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

In my form there almost 30-35 controls, some are enabled and some are disabled like spouse name is disabled if the the person is unmarried and if the user selects that they are married the control get enabled.

Initially the submit button is disabled but as soon as all enabled fields are filled I want the submit button to automatically enable itself.

I have done this code for this purpose.

```
if ((nametxt.Text != null) && (f_nametxt.Text != null) &&
    (m_nametxt.Text != null) && (gotra_txt.Text != null) &&
    (panthcb.Text != null) && (fhntext.Text != null) &&
    (edulvlcb.Text != null) && (bloodcb.Text != null) &&
    (MarritalStatus != null) && (s_nametxt.Text != null) &&
    (s_edulvlcb.Text != null) && (s_bgcb.Text != null) &&
    (ressi_addresstxt.Text != null) && (ressi_phnotxt.Text != null) &&
    (mobi_notxt.Text != null) && (office_addresstxt.Text != null) &&
    (occup_typetxt.Text != null) && (occup_naturecb.Text != null) &&
    (office_phno1txt.Text != null) && (office_mobnotxt.Text != null))
{
   submit_addbtn.Enabled = true;
}
```

I don't whether this is correct or not and where (at which event of form) I should do this.

Please tell me and help me.

Here is the code done keydown event of text boxes and this event is not triggering

```
 private void mobi_notxt_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            TextBox txt = c as TextBox;
            if (txt != null)
            {
                if (!(txt.Enabled && txt.Text != ""))
                {
                    allFilled = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (allFilled)
        {
            submit_addbtn.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            submit_addbtn.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `mobi_notxt_KeyDown` assigned to all your textboxes?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all your TextBox controls and check if they are enabled. If they are you check the Text property.

```
bool allFilled = true;

foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    TextBox txt = c as TextBox;
    if (txt != null)
    {
        if (txt.Enabled && txt.Text == "")
        {
            allFilled = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (allFilled) 
{
    button1.Enabled = true;
} else
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

As a result your allFilled boolean will be true if every enabled field contains something and false in the other case.

You can assign it on any event you like.
For example on a key down event which you assign to all your Text boxes

Comment: In conjunction with this, you'd want to use a timer to check the state of the text boxes every second or two in order to automatically enable your submit button.

i.e. On the tick event of the timer call a method that contains the `foreach` loop described above and use the `allFilled` bool to set `button.Enabled = true;`

Comment: @Kobunite Isn't a key down event on every text box better? Then it will trigger on all the right moments and not randomly when it's not even necessary

Comment: Couldn't a key down event cause many calls in quick succession as it'll trigger whenever any key is pressed on every text box? I might be wrong, I haven't used key down events in a while.

Comment: It will, but I don't think you'll notice. I use a key down event in a form just to check if you press enter and submit the form then. And it's not a noticable difference

Comment: means i have declare bool all filled at class level the at the key down or any other event of all the text boxes present in my code i should paste this code. but where i have to code the if allfilled = true button.enable=true

Comment: just behind this. Edited my post

Comment: Fair enough, a Key Down would work - personally I'd prefer the over head of a timer calling it every so often rather than the key down calls but thats just how I'd do it.

Comment: Is your Key down event triggering?

Comment: You should update your original question to show your key down event and where you assign it to your Text Boxes